# Danish Assistant Professor job offer and recognition of Master's degree

Tags: degree, denmark

I am happy to have received a job offer from a Danish university and we are currently discussing the salary. The salaries in Denmark are negotiated by a collective agreement and there are fixed scales for everything. So what is crucial is to make sure that I land on the right scale.

I have completed a 3 year (180 ECTS) undergraduate degree and a one year Masters degree (90 ECTS) before doing a PhD also in a European country. I can confirm that my PhD degree is recognized as a fully equivalent to a Danish PhD degree.

I am told that since my Master's degree with 90 ECTS is not equivalent to a Danish master's degree (which typically has 120 ECTS), the university can not put me on the salary scale for their regular Assistant Professors. Rather, I am put on a lower scale that puts me at a financial disadvantage.

Is this even possible? By deduction, since they do not recognize my Master's degree but a Master's degree is a prerequisite to do a PhD in Denmark and my PhD is deemed equivalent, this would imply that technically, the institution does not recognize my PhD degree?

This seems inconsistent with the confirmation that my PhD degree is recognized as being equivalent to a Danish PhD.

Is this a catch 22?

Kind regards!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. I assume that you want more than knowing whether or not this would count as a catch 22 situation (if you don't, the question would be off-topic). Please edit your question and make clear what it is we should help you with.

Comment: You might ask if the same issue would occur with a US Ph.D who never got a master's. Perhaps the longer duration would make up for the missing master's in a US case?